# R - adding a count table in a dataframe

Tags: r, count, dplyr, pivot-table

I would like to get a count table from several values in my dataframe, which are spread over several columns.
In my case, several of my subjects have one or more types of medication. Now they are mentioned in several columns. I would instead like to have each medication name in a separate column, and a 1 or 0 (a count) per subject if they have it or not.

For example, my dataframe now looks like:

```
Pp  X           X2              X3              X4 
1   NA          NA              NA              NA 
2   trimipramin NA              NA              NA
3   Quetiapin   venlafaxin      escitalopram    NA 
4   duloxetin   amitriptylin    NA              NA
5   quetiapin   citalopram      escitalopram    Lithium 
6   NA          NA              NA              NA
7   duloxetin   escitalopram    venlafaxin      NA
```

I would like to it look like:

```
Pp  trimipramin escitalopram    quetiapin   venlafaxin  duloxetin   …
1   0           0               0           0           0           …
2   1           0               0           0           0           …
3   0           1               1           1           0           …
4   0           0               0           0           1           …   
5   0           1               1           0           0           …
6   0           0               0           0           0           …
7   0           1               0           1           1           …
```

Would it be possible to get such a count table added to my dataframe and not separately? 
I assume dplyr's `spread()` might be useful in this case, but I couldn't get it to work :-(
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)

data %>% gather(key = "Med", value = "Value", -Pp) %>% select(-Med) %>% 
         dcast(Pp~Value,fun.aggregate = function(x){as.integer(length(x) > 0)})
```

## Data

```
data <- read.table(text="
        Pp  X           X2              X3              X4 
        1   NA          NA              NA              NA 
        2   trimipramin NA              NA              NA
        3   Quetiapin   venlafaxin      escitalopram    NA 
        4   duloxetin   amitriptylin    NA              NA
        5   quetiapin   citalopram      escitalopram    Lithium 
        6   NA          NA              NA              NA
        7   duloxetin   escitalopram    venlafaxin      NA",header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `table` function in `base` is a simple method for creating this type of binary indicator matrix.

```
library(tidyverse)

D %>%
  gather(key, drug, -Pp) %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  table

#>Pp  amitriptylin citalopram duloxetin escitalopram Lithium ...
#> 1             0          0         0            0       0 ... 
#> 2             0          0         0            0       0 ... 
#> 3             0          0         0            1       0 ... 
#> 4             1          0         1            0       0 ... 
#> 5             0          1         0            1       1 ... 
#> 6             0          0         0            0       0 ... 
#> 7             0          0         1            1       0 ...
```

You can also do it using `spread` instead, but this solution will remove patients without any associated drugs:

```
D %>%
  gather(key, value, -Pp) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  mutate(key=1) %>%
  spread(value, key, fill=0, drop = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it is the easiest solution, but it works. First you have to get all medications in a vector. I do that with `unlist` and `unqiue`. Then you have to loop through them and and get the number of cases. I do that with the `apply` function and the sum of matches. As you want it in the same `data.frame` you can store it with `data[[name]]`. This solution works without any packages.

```
names = as.character(na.omit(unique(unlist(data))))
for(name in names){
  data[[name]] = apply(data, FUN = function(x) { sum(x == name, na.rm = T) }, 1)
}
```

## Data

```
data = read.table(text = "X           X2              X3              X4 
NA          NA              NA              NA 
trimipramin NA              NA              NA
Quetiapin   venlafaxin      escitalopram    NA 
duloxetin   amitriptylin    NA              NA
quetiapin   citalopram      escitalopram    Lithium 
NA          NA              NA              NA
duloxetin   escitalopram    venlafaxin      NA", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```